# How to update the whole array of objects using Put http request with a json raw body?

Tags: json, angular, api, rest, postman

I have a json Array something like below and I want to make an update to the whole list without passing by a specefic ID.

- List before update

  [ { id:"1", name : "name_1" }, { id:"2", name : "name_2" } ]
- Wanted list after update

  [ { id:"1", name : "name_3" }, { id:"2", name : "name_4" } ]

I tried using **PUT** request and passing the target list in a json raw body, but it always return **"404 not found"**

I tried it with Postman but it returns the same error. Is it possible to do like so ?

Comment: "Is it possible to do like so" - like what? do you have any code?

Comment: the 404 error means that Url of the API is wrong!! and if you want to edit array in local , then you can use .map function

Comment: This might be the backend issue. Nothing to do with the frontend.

Comment: There is no error concerning the URL. The problem is if I specify an ID it works perfectly but what I want is to update the whole list.